# Caliburn.Micro automatically activating a ViewModel which it shouldn't

Tags: c#, wpf, castle-windsor, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro as a WPF framework, and my app is modelled more or less of the exemplar code from the CM doco. I am using Castle.Windsor as an IoC container.

My ShellViewModel has a corresponding view which shows 'child' views in a tab control. All was well, but somehow I've now managed to get it to start activating a particular view model which it shouldn't be.

I am explicitly calling `ActivateItem(SomeViewModel)` from my `ShellViewModel` to get 3 tabs opened. This is fine. But CM is automatically activating a 4th ViewModel (let's call it `NotYetViewModel`) which I am not asking it to do.

The stack trace seems to suggest that this is because Castle.Windsor is calling a `Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstance(...)` with this ViewModel type, and this has the side-effect of having its view loaded and shown when it shouldn't be.

`NotYetViewModel` is not a dependency of any of the ViewModels which I *do* want to activate, nor is it referenced in any way from the `ShellViewModel`, which the bootstrapper is creating, so I am lost as to what would cause CM/Castle to try and create an instance of this VM without my explicitly asking it to.

Only other clue I have is that if I remove the default constructor from `NotYetViewModel`, it is not created (presumably because CM/Castle *can't* create it), but no errors are reported for this failure, which suggests Castle doesn't think this type is a required dependency of something else.

Any suggestions on what I could look into to resolve this?

Comment: Whilst I still don't know what's caused this, in the course of further debugging, I've discovered the problem "goes away" with Castle.Windsor.dll v3.2

Comment: Strange one that, I'm using Windsor and not had that problem, what version of Windsor were you experiencing this with?

Comment: Was happening in 3.1, but only for 1 VM out of many, and I can't explain why.

Comment: Must be a dependency somewhere that it thinks needs injecting - might be worth looking at the graph generated by Windsor (inspect the `Kernel` property in the container at runtime iirc or there might be another property, it's pretty obvious) and see if you can find where the dependency lies. Did you add property injection via CMs `BuildUp` method or did you just leave it as constructor injection only?

Comment: I am using BuildUp, as well as CI. The component is a valid dependency which should exist in Castle's graph, but it *shouldn't* be getting activated in the CM world. That's the bit that isn't making sense, and seems to be resolved in 3.2.